# Missing files (404) in Ionic App only in iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app I developed in Android. I installed a VM with Mac, and I'm testing it in iOS. The app worked perfectly in Android, but in iOS it is not. When I use 'ionic serve' or 'ionic serve --lab' the browser show a white screen, and in the console I get this errors (link of image below):

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaLrT.png)

Here is some code from the index.html:

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic.cloud.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic-modal-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic-toast.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I'm really lost here because the exact same files works OK for Android.

Comment: Are you sure your external resource files are accessible from the VM running MAC instance? MAybe you are trying to fetch `localhost` resources, which VM is not able to reach...

Comment: All the files are in the VM locally, I'm not using any file from the 'real' machine.

Comment: And you are sure the includes are valid?

Comment: @daan.desmedt thanks for pointing out that in fact i was missing the lib folder. Apparently the checkout of the SVN didn't download that folder. Now when using ionic serve I get a blank screen, and no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Which error you are posted, not library error.Error coming from app.js file.If you dont mind create a new ionic app and replace your file in new app.it will works.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: OK, I started a blank project and it works. I copied the js files, the css and img folders and everything its good. I copied the templates folder. No errors, but in the moment that I put the '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>' in the index file, the page goes blank, with no errors.

Comment: I feel like it is a problem with the routing.

Comment: <body ng-app="starter" >
  <div ng-include="'templates/partials/header.html'" ng-if="location != 'landing' && header == true"></div>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>  :::: try this and make sure ng-app name same as define in your app.js file

Comment: it worked! But I don't know why happened that. Can you elaborate in an answer?